# How to change size of a textView of fragment from main Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, textview

**I want to change the size of a fragment textview from main activity. Note: There is no error. I can display perfectly find in my application but changing size I have a problem. Please help. Thank you**

```
       // This is from Main Activity

       TextView changeTextSize;
       .
       .
       LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment,null);

       changeTextSize = view.findViewById(R.id.engdetails);
       System.out.println(changeTextSize.getText().toString()); // This prints the informatin of engdetails without any error //Testing purpose 
       changeTextSize.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,30);  // This does not change the size I have tried changeTextSize.setTextSize(30) too
```

** Note: There is no error on running or debugging**

Comment: Try to use `findViewById` only, instead of `view.findViewById`

Comment: @artenson.art98 I have tried that before and I retry it again. It didn't work

Comment: The above code retreive the data fine and it can be displayed using system.out for testing purpose but when changing the textsize, it does not change

Comment: Can you change the text color or the textview content (the actual text) in this way? Do you inflate this layout in the `Fragment` itself?